# Correctly loading admin scripts in Wordpress 5.0.0

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to load some scripts to the editor page of my Wordpress admin, and although I can see that the scripts have loaded correctly, and with no console errors, the functionality they should provide is not working.

More specifically, I am trying to load flickity.js, to enable a slideshow to function when viewing the element in the new Guternberg editor.

The code being used with functions.php to load the scripts is as follows, where 'flickity' is the library, and 'single' contains the init script.:

```
function my_enqueue($hook) {

    wp_register_script('flickity', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/vendor/min/flickity.pkgd-min.js', false, '2.1.0', true);
    wp_register_script('single', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/min/single-min.js', false, '1.0', true);

    wp_enqueue_script('flickity');
    wp_enqueue_script('single');
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue');
```

Comment: Have your scripts no dependencies? Or you have a problem with missing styles.

Comment: No dependencies apart from Jquery, which is already loaded. I tried loading that again, but no difference. Missing styles are not the problem, because I can see that the DOM elements that should be inserted by Flickity are not happening, so the initialisation isn't happening correctly?